# How can I avoid the following behaviour?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am creating a modal component that shows a document stored in firebase... when I click I send the document id by porps.

then when closing the modal the document remains in the state and when I want to reopen the same document it shows nothing...

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ContextGlobal } from "../../context/documentosContext";

export default function ActualizarDocumento(props) {
    const { docRef, mostrarDocumento } = useContext(ContextGlobal);
    const [abrirDocumento, setAbrirDocumento] = useState(mostrarDocumento);

    useEffect(() => {
        try {
            if (props.id !== "") {
                docRef(props.id);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error :", error);
        }
    }, [props.id]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setAbrirDocumento(mostrarDocumento);
    }, [mostrarDocumento]);

    return (
        <>
            {props.modalActualizar && (
                <div>
                    <div>{abrirDocumento.titulo}</div>
                    <button
                        title="Cerrar"
                        onClick={() => {
                            props.setModalActualizar(!props.setModalActualizar);
                            setAbrirDocumento("");
                        }}
                        className="btn btn-outline-secondary border-0"
                    >
                        <i className="bi bi-x-lg" />
                    </button>
                </div>
            )}
        </>
    );
}
```

this video show the unwanted behavior https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AivOtYJsTk0XWTgutup179qGbvqN78dI/view

In case I need to open the same document, let me do it.